# Faking SqlConnection and embedded methods in the NUnit Test, using FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, nunit, fakeiteasy

I have the following class and methods, that will be connecting to a DB, but for testing, I do not need the real connection and would need to fake it. We're using FakeItEasy for this.:

```
public abstract class HandlerBase
    {
        public string errorMessage;

        private MyActionsDataModel Action
        {
            get
            {
                if (_action == null)
                {
                    _action = new MyActionsDataModel();
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Connections.MyDatabase))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
                        {
                            _action.Id = connection.QuerySingle<int>("UpdateAction", transaction: transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: Action);
                            transaction.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _action;
            }
        }
        private MyActionsDataModel _action;

        public void RecordFailure(AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A failure happened:");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
            errorMessage = "Inner Exception\r\n" + ex.Message;
            Action.ErrorOccurredOnUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            Action.ErrorType = ex.GetType().FullName;
            Action.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            SaveAction();
        }

        private void SaveAction()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Connections.MyDatabase))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
                {
                    connection.Execute("UpdateAction", transaction: transaction,
                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: Action);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

another class that I'll be calling in my tests:

```
public class MyHandlerType : HandlerBase
    {
        private readonly MyTracker _myTracker;

        public MyHandlerType(MyTracker myTracker) : base()
        {
            _myTracker = myTracker;
        }
    }
```

What I want is to Fake the **Action** parameter and also **SaveAction** method.

Here is the Test I have for it, but not sure how to make the Fake part.

```
public class HandlerTests
    {
        [TestCase]
        public void Test_RecordFailure()
        {
            var innerMessage = "Throw AppException for UnitTest.";
            var parentMessage = "Throw AggregationException for UnitTest.";

            var testHandler = new MyHandlerType(null);
            var innerException = new ApplicationException(innerMessage);
            var parentException = new AggregateException(parentMessage, innerException);
            testHandler.RecordFailure(parentException);
            var includeInnerMessage = testHandler.errorMessage.Contains(innerMessage);
            var includeParentMessage = testHandler.errorMessage.Contains(parentMessage);

            Assert.IsTrue(includeInnerMessage);
            Assert.IsTrue(includeParentMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are code smells in the code as shown. Are you willing to refactor the code to follow the usually recommended standard (SOLID Principles). Allowing more maintainable code that can also be tested in isolation.

Comment: @Nkosi, Thanks. Yes, I'm willing to refactor it - to make it better and achieve my test goal

Comment: @Nkosi, will you be able to provide guidance to the refactoring? I'm still stuck with the test part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current class is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that make testing it in isolation difficult.

Consider refactoring the class

```
public abstract class HandlerBase {
    private readonly Lazy<MyActionsDataModel> model;
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    protected HandlerBase(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        model = new Lazy<MyActionsDataModel>(() => {
            MyActionsDataModel action = new MyActionsDataModel();
            using (DbConnection connection = this.connectionFactory.Create()) {
                connection.Open();
                using (DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)) {
                    action.Id = connection.QuerySingle<int>("UpdateAction",
                        transaction: transaction,
                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                        param: action);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            return action;
        });           
    }

    public string ErrorMessage;

    public void RecordFailure(AggregateException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("A failure happened:");
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
        ErrorMessage = "Inner Exception\r\n" + ex.Message;
        MyActionsDataModel action = model.Value;
        action.ErrorOccurredOnUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        action.ErrorType = ex.GetType().FullName;
        action.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
        saveAction(action);
    }

    private void saveAction(MyActionsDataModel action) {
        using (DbConnection connection = connectionFactory.Create()) {
            connection.Open();
            using (DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)) {
                connection.Execute("UpdateAction", transaction: transaction,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: action);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the introduction of an explicit dependency

```
public interface IDbConnectionFactory {
    DbConnection Create();
}
```

which can have an implementation

```
// Connection Factory method
public DbConnection Create() {
    DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Connections.MyDatabase);
    return connection;
}
```

When testing the factory can be mocked to behave as desired when the subject under test is exercised.

Comment: thanks a lot @Nkosi for the help with refactoring and the hint on the faking. I have implemented my test part. The only thing is not really working for me (and I cannot figure out why) is "DbConnection connection = connectionFactory.Create()" in the "saveAction()" method. It does not get the ConnectionString value, as it does correctly in the HandlerBase constructor (and I thought it should keep it the same as from the HandlerBase constructor above). Any thought on why or how to properly fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new code (based on the suggestion from @Nkosi) and the test part:

CODE:

```
    public abstract class HandlerBase {
        private readonly Lazy<MyActionsDataModel> model;
        private readonly IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    
        protected HandlerBase(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
            model = new Lazy<MyActionsDataModel>(() => {
                MyActionsDataModel action = new MyActionsDataModel();
                using (DbConnection connection = this.connectionFactory.Create()) {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)) {
                        action.Id = connection.QuerySingle<int>("UpdateAction",
                            transaction: transaction,
                            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                            param: action);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
                return action;
            });           
        }
    
        public string ErrorMessage;
    
        public void RecordFailure(AggregateException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("A failure happened:");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
            ErrorMessage = "Inner Exception\r\n" + ex.Message;
            MyActionsDataModel action = model.Value;
            action.ErrorOccurredOnUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            action.ErrorType = ex.GetType().FullName;
            action.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
            saveAction(action);
        }
    
        private void saveAction(MyActionsDataModel action) {
            using (DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Connections.MyDatabase)) {
                connection.Open();
                using (DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)) {
                    connection.Execute("UpdateAction", transaction: transaction,
                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: action);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public interface IDbConnectionFactory {
        DbConnection Create();
    }
    
    // Connection Factory method
    public DbConnection Create() {
        DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Connections.MyDatabase);
        return connection;
    }


public class MyHandlerType : HandlerBase
    {
        private readonly IDbConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;

        public MyHandlerType(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) : base(connectionFactory)
        {
            _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        }
}
```

TEST:

```
public class HandlerTests
    {
        protected MyHandlerType _subjectUnderTest;
        protected HandlerBase.IDbConnectionFactory _fakeConnectionFactory;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _fakeConnectionFactory = A.Fake<HandlerBase.IDbConnectionFactory>();
            A.CallTo(() => _fakeConnectionFactory.Create()).Returns<DbConnection>(new SqlConnection(Constants.Connections.MyDatabase));

            _subjectUnderTest = new MyHandlerType(_fakeConnectionFactory);
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void Test_RecordFailure()
        {
            var innerMessage = "Throw AppException for UnitTest.";
            var parentMessage = "Throw AggregationException for UnitTest.";
            var innerException = new ApplicationException(innerMessage);
            var parentException = new AggregateException(parentMessage, innerException);
            _subjectUnderTest.RecordFailure(parentException);
            var includeInnerMessage = testHandler.errorMessage.Contains(innerMessage);
            var includeParentMessage = testHandler.errorMessage.Contains(parentMessage);

            Assert.IsTrue(includeInnerMessage);
            Assert.IsTrue(includeParentMessage);
        }
    }
```